# How to improve performance of an OpenCV algorithm written in C++

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, optimization, raspberry-pi

I am executing a computer vision program written in C++ and OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3B and my camera module is picamera. Roughly I am calculating the deviation amount from the road and sending it to another platform.

Currently, my main methodology can not become simpler i.e, i can't remove any matrix operations. However, I need to increase my throughput further. For the time being, I receive 19-20 results per second. My camera FPS is set to 30.

I was wondering are there any way to increase throughput? For example, I have tried to use optimization levels on g++ (-O2, -O3) and didn't observe any increase.

Another option is to use multithreading since my throuhput is lower than camera FPS maybe i can capture another frame while other thread processing the already captured frame. However, I don't have any experience in multithreading therefore I wanted to ask whether anyone can approve this strategy or not since I have limited time I want to use my effort in the most fruitful way.

Any other suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Profile your code with valgrind/callgrind or gprof

Comment: I find I normally get a massive boost from multithreading, but measure your performance carefully. First see how many fps you can achieve with no processing at all, simply discarding frames - this will be your absolute max fps. Then try running your processing with static data, i.e. no acquisition at all. Then see what you can "hide" behind the acquisition using threads.

Comment: @sezgin1947 inside raspberry pi 3, there's a gpu module called videocore, you could use that for accelerating. multithread is also a choice here but, before go multi-thread, check your cpu usage first. i think you're already running at multiple-thread.